# R: Improving performance for copying data from a small to a big table

Tags: r, performance, data.table

**Desired Process**

I am doing quite a standard procedure. I would like the entries from the small data.table called `SMALL` at columns `a` and `b` to be entered in the big data.table called `BIG` by respecting the shared values at the columns `value1` and `value2`.

The following does the job but is way too slow for my purpose

```
BIG$a = 0
BIG$b = 0
for (value1 in unique(SMALL$value1))
{
  for (value2 in unique(SMALL$value2[SMALL$value1==value1]))
  {
    position_BIG        = BIG$value1 == value1 & BIG$value2 == value2
    position_SMALL      = SMALL$value1 == value1 & SMALL$value2 == value2
    BIG$a[position_BIG] = SMALL$a[position_SMALL]
    BIG$b[position_BIG] = SMALL$b[position_SMALL]
  }
}
```

**Notes**

- For each combination of `value1` and `value2` there is always a single entry in `SMALL` and at least one entry in `BIG`
- There are about 10 unique `value1`
- There are about 200 unique values `value2`
- `SMALL` contains about 2000 rows
- `BIG` contains about 10^9 rows

**Question**

- Is there a way to improve the speed of this operation?
- Would `Rccp` be of any help here?
- Would it make a difference if I write the vectors `BIGa` and `BIGb` first and then do `BIG$a=BIGa` and `BIG$b=BIGb`
- Would it help to use `rep()` on the right side of the "equation" in the "slow part"?

Comment: Your example is not reproducible, so it's pretty hard to test anything. Having said that, it looks like you may want to try `merge()` after setting the keys to `value1` and `value2`. The data.table package implements a very fast version of `merge`.

Comment: Success with that code seems rather doubtful. The range of possible values position_BIG and  position_SMALL is [0,1]. So in addition to not being not reproducible it's also unclear. You definitely should make a small test case of two dataframes, since you have apparently not done any testing.